# fill gap between alphanumeric array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling with a simple pattern :

`['A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'E1', 'E4', 'E6']`

I would like to fill the numeric gap (in place or in another array) between each range of alphanumerics

The pattern is 1 letter concatenated with an integer greater than 1 (if you feel to do with any number of letter aswell feel free)

So this exemple array would result in the following :

`['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5', 'E6']`

I'm looking for the most straightforward/efficient way, ES6 welcomed too

Comment: Couldn't you just overwrite the array with a new one?

Comment: Is this always 1 Character and 1 Number or could it be CA32 as well?

Comment: What do you mean by _“I'm struggling”_? Do you have an attempt that you could show us?

Comment: It's always 1 character but can be any number > 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate through your array once to collect the following information:

- what alpha parts do you have
- what are left and right (min and max) boundaries for each alpha part

In your example, after first iteration we will know that there are two alphas:

- A, starting from 1 and going up to 5
- E, starting from 1 and going up to 6

Now, you can just generate the answer.

**Demo:**

```js
var sourceYours = ['A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'E1', 'E4', 'E6']
var sourceComplex = ['A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'E1', 'E4', 'E6', 'D2', 'D4', 'E7'];

console.log(fillGaps(sourceYours));
console.log(fillGaps(sourceComplex));

function fillGaps(arr) {
  var alphas = {};
  
  arr.forEach(function(x) {
    var alpha = x.replace(/\d/, ""), 
        numeric = +x.replace(/\D/, "");
    
    if (!alphas[alpha]) {
      alphas[alpha] = {
        min: numeric,
        max: numeric
      };
    } else {
      alphas[alpha].min = Math.min(alphas[alpha].min, numeric);
      alphas[alpha].max = Math.max(alphas[alpha].max, numeric);
    }    
  });
  
  var result = [];
  for (var alpha in alphas)
  {
    for (var num = alphas[alpha].min; num <= alphas[alpha].max; num++)
    {
      result.push(alpha + num);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

This solution has many places to be improved or shortened and it depends on your ECMASript version limitations, but it shows the idea.
I have also assumed that this format is always guarantted: `{alpha part}{numeric part}`. If it is not, then it needs to be improved too.

Comment: This offers certainly one of the more verbose solutions, but it is also the easiest read.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `reduce` method.

Also, use `replace` method by passing a `regex` pattern in order to find out `text` from `E1` which is `E` or `number` which is `1`.

The idea is looking to two elements `consecutive` from your given array and add the missing elems using a `for` **loop**.

```js
let array=['A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'E1', 'E4', 'E6']
array = array.reduce(function(arr,item,i){
  if(i>0){
    var [elemNr,elemStr]=[item.replace( /\D+/g, ''),item.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')];
    var [lastElemNr, lastElemStr]=[array[i-1].replace( /\D+/g, ''),array[i-1].replace(/[0-9]/g, '')];
    for(j=lastElemNr;j<=elemNr;j++) 
       if(arr.indexOf(elemStr+j)==-1)
          arr.push(elemStr+j);
  }
  return arr;
},[]);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers has a max value, you can also think about Hash-Map/Table (e.g. Dictionary).

```
var sourceYours = ['A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'E1', 'E4', 'E6']
```

1. Get Alpha-Part
2. Find Max-Numeric-Part of that Alpha
3. Get Dictionary-Entry of "A5" -> returning `['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']`
4. concat all dictionary-returns

Should be the fastest way. Costs more memory. Has to create Dictionary first.
Expects limited maximum Number-Part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function fill(theArray){
  theArray = theArray.sort().reverse();
  var newList = [];
  for (let el of theArray) {
    let newListLenght = newList.length;
    if (!newListLenght || newList[newListLenght-1].charAt(0) !== el.charAt(0)){
      let maxNumber = parseInt(el.charAt(1));
      for (let number = 1; number < maxNumber; number ++){
        newList.push(el.charAt(0) + number);
      }
    }
  };
  return newList.sort();
}
```

Works even with disordered elements

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where you have a look to two elements of the given array and fill the missing parts with a `while` loop, while counting up.

```js
var array = ['Z0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'B4','E1', 'E4', 'E6', 'G2'],
    result = [];

array.reduce(function (a, b) {
    var aa = (a || b).match(/(\D+)(\d+)/).slice(1),
        bb = b.match(/(\D+)(\d+)/).slice(1);

    if (aa[0] === bb[0]) {
        while (++aa[1] < bb[1]) {
            result.push(aa.join(''));
        }
    }
    result.push(b);
    return b;
}, undefined);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop the original array and then compare the if the values are consecutive. If they are not, you can fill up that difference using a loop.

For example:

```
var result = [];
var arr = ['A1', 'A2', 'A5', 'E1', 'E4', 'E6'];
arr.sort();

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var curr = arr[i];
    result.push(curr);
    if (arr[i + 1]) {
        var next = arr[i + 1];
        if (curr.charAt(1) < next.charAt(1)) {
            for (var y = parseInt(curr.charAt(1), 10) + 1 ; y < parseInt(next.charAt(1)); y++) {
                result.push(next.charAt(0) + y);
            }
        }

    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Will result in:

> ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6"]